# what's this file in java? core.26416, heap dump or thread dump?

Tags: java, heap-memory, coredump, heap-dump, thread-dump

core.26416 ,what's this file in java?  which tool can anaylst it? what's the extension for java thread dump , heap dump and core? what's the difference between thread dump/heap dump and core dump?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what is core.26416 file i do not know, but Thread Dump basically helps to track a activity of each thread.What are the job/task each thread is doing at a perticular point of time we can get by thread dump.

To Create a thread dump in console Press Ctrl+Pause Break from Key board.

Create a java program for infinite loop , at the time of running press Ctrl+Pause Break key from key board and see the Full Thread dump is printed on console ( Now write that into a file).

Program :- xLoop.java

> public class xLoop{   public static void main(String str[]){  boolean
>   x=true;           while(x){       System.out.println("Hello Manoj ");     }   } }

**Heap Dump**

But, Heap dump is used to find memory leak.Thread dump may not give 100% of result for finding memory leak, so you can use heap dump for achieve this.Heap dump is essential for heap size,perm size and some other setups.

There are many tools like **jhat** is a heap analysis tool or you can use **[visualgc](http://java.sun.com/performance/jvmstat/),[jmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html)** are very popular tools for heap dump.